# How to slide in a top bar in the view in WinJS/HTML app

Tags: html, animation, winjs

Which animation I would have to use to slide in a top aligned bar into the view?

I only see `WinJS.UI.Animation.slideDown` but it slides it of to the bottom of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand correctly but if you want to place an AppBar at the top, so it'll appear when you swipe down from the top you need to set the [`placement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700567.aspx) property of the AppBar to `top`.

Keep in mind this property is not supported on Windows Phone, where AppBars are always placed at bottom.

Comment: No, I am not talking about an app-bar. Its a notification bar I want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Try [WinJS.UI.Animation.showEdgeUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230466.aspx) and [hideEdgeUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212676.aspx) instead. Should work from any edge in any direction (and is what the app bar uses, for instance).

Comment: what would be my `options` be in that case?

Comment: Usually it's just { mechanism: "transition" } .